# XSD Validation - minLength attribute does not work

Tags: c#, xsd, xml-parsing, xsd-validation

I want to validate one of the required data field which contains a string. data are in a tab delimited file. I have created a simpleType as below,

```
<xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Barcode" type="String20"/>

<xsd:simpleType name="String20">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
        <xsd:maxLength value="20"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

This validation does not break when the data is empty. I also changed minLength to 2 and tested with one character, but it did not break on that too.

Does any one know how to validate empty string please?

Thanks

Comment: How are you using XSD to validate a Tab Delimited File?

Comment: Works as expected under .net and xerces

Comment: I'm using XmlReaderSettings() in C#. and use XmlSchemaSet() to set my xsd schema

Comment: Maybe there is an issue with the validation code. Post the code you use to do the validation

Comment: I had a similar issue and was only able to fix it thanks to feedback from guys here telling me to use an assert. Maybe that is what will help you?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69195370/how-to-force-a-comlpextype-element-to-have-at-least-3-characters-in-a-string